# Source of this story of a Jewish woman and the prophet?

Tags: hadith, source-identification, islamic-basis

There is a *very* popular story that narrates like this

> It goes that a Jewish woman in Mecca who would throw garbage on the
>   doorstep of the Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) in defiance
>   of his message, and one day she fell sick and could not throw the
>   garbage, so the Prophet (peace be upon him) visited her.  Then it is
>   said that she was so amazed at his character that she realized his
>   prophethood and accepted Islam. [source](http://seekersguidance.org/ans-blog/2011/02/11/is-it-true-that-someone-threw-trash-on-the-prophet-peace-and-blessings-of-allah-be-upon-him/)

**Is there any reference of this story in book of hadith or otherwise?** I have seen this narrated many times in school and in every day life by others. In one of story, it even has her name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is no authentic source for the above story**. Script [from my own link above](http://seekersguidance.org/ans-blog/2011/02/11/is-it-true-that-someone-threw-trash-on-the-prophet-peace-and-blessings-of-allah-be-upon-him/) says

> **I have not found a basis for this specific incident in the books of
>   hadeeth or reliable works of prophetic biography**, and it seems as
>   though this story has become popular on the tongues of people without
>   any source to support it, and Allah knows best.

This means this story as it is did not happen. It mainly propagated from mouth to mouth or from books which are not considered a major work.

The above link does mention, the prophet **was** thrown filth on his head by other mushrikeen, mostly males. Only one female did something similar to the prophet, it was Umm Jamil, the wife of Abu Lahab (the prophet paternal uncle). She would gather thorny branches and palm branches and place it in way overnight where prophet Muhammad would walk). The prophet issued her forgiveness after the conquest of Mecca.